# Preference Bundle Toggle issue on iOS 7

Tags: ios, toggle, bundle, preference

So, I'm at my wits end...
I'm a novice w/ little experience making iOS jailbreak tweaks. I'm hoping my question will help others trying to figure out the same thing.

I have a simple tweak that has a Preference Bundle. Everything is setup except my PSSwitchCell toggle will not work for enabling or disabling my tweak.  I've searched and read tons of tutorials but I can't find the 'magic' answer to fix my problem!

This package disables or enables the PLAY button across iOS. Basically, if the Toggle is on (enabled) then I want my tweak to work; if it's off, I want to call %orig.  I assume the switch isn't reading my Tweak.xm file the way I want it to.

I started by using the [tutorial from Aehmlo](http://blog.aehmlo.com/2012/08/03/new-tweak-readme/) and have edited it a little...sorry

Can you all help?

Tweak.xm:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MPAVController.h>


%hook MPAVController

-(void)play {

// Disables the PLAY button

NSDictionary *prefs=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.me.mytweak.plist"];

//Points my Preference Bundle to my tweak


if ([prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"]){

    return;
    // If my toggle is enabled, disable the PLAY button

        }else{

            %orig;
            // If my toggle is OFF, enable the PLAY button
}

}

%end
```

MyTweaks.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSSwitchCell</string>
            <key>default</key>
            <false/>
            <key>defaults</key>
            <string>com.me.mytweak</string>
            <key>key</key>
            <string>enabled</string>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>Enable</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSButtonCell</string>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>Respring to Apply Changes</string>
            <key>action</key>
            <string>respring</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSGroupCell</string>
            <key>footerText</key>
            <string>iTortrix.com, 2014.</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>MyTweak</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I edited this post to show the most basic setup for this tweak.  It still doesn't work, though...  Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I fixed the problem!  I should've left something in my script that was originally in aehmlo's tutorial.  I needed to include boolValue at the end of my 'if' statement.  That was it!!!

```
if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"enabled"] boolValue]){
```

Glad I figured it out.